# Is this the best way to split the string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have seen one of my friends splitting and copying one string into another like this.

```
char str[] = "05/09/2013";
char day[3];
char month[3];
char year[5];

memset(day, 0, sizeof(day));
memset(month, 0, sizeof(month));
memset(year, 0, sizeof(year));

month[0] = str[0];
month[1] = str[1];
day[0]   = str[2];
day[1]   = str[3];
year[0]  = str[4];
year[1]  = str[5];
year[2]  = str[6];
year[3]  = str[7];

month[2] = '\0';
day[2]   = '\0';
year[4]  = '\0';
```

I heard about `strtok` and `strsep`, but what's wrong with the above way of copying? What are the issues I will face if I proceed with the above method?

Comment: have you heard of [strtok](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)

Comment: For one thing, you don't check to see if the it's actually a valid date.  Ignoring that, the memsets are a waste of time.

Comment: I didn't ask about the validity of the date, anyways I already have the function for validation. Read my question before you comment. @LucasHolt

Comment: @emb-pro Lucas is giving you valuable input, so please stop being rude. So you have validation code, that's great and Lucas can't know that. Still the `memset()`s are completely superfluous.

Comment: simply `sscanf(str, "%2s/%2s/%4s", day, month, year);`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is a broken way, as this little sample demonstrates:

```
#include <stdio.h>                         
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "05/09/2013";
    char day[3];
    char month[3];
    char year[5];

    memset(day, 0, sizeof(day));
    memset(month, 0, sizeof(month));
    memset(year, 0, sizeof(year));

    month[0] = str[0];
    month[1] = str[1];
    day[0]   = str[2];
    day[1]   = str[3];
    year[0]  = str[4];
    year[1]  = str[5];
    year[2]  = str[6];
    year[3]  = str[7];

    month[2] = '\0';
    day[2]   = '\0';
    year[4]  = '\0';

    printf("%s.%s.%s\n", day, month, year);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> $ ./splitdate
>   /0.05.9/20

Oh right, you got your indices wrong!

So, you see the first and most important shortcoming of your solution: **It's hard to maintain**. In terms of performance, it's probably close to the best possible, but really, performance **is not an issue** with such ridiculously small data sets.

If you don't mind modifying your original string, [`strtok()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) is the best bet for you. If your requirements are more complicated, write your own parser.

Modified code using `strtok()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "05/09/2013";
    char *month = strtok(str, "/");
    char *day = strtok(0, "/");
    char *year = strtok(0, "/");

    printf("%s.%s.%s\n", day, month, year);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> $ ./splitdate
>   09.05.2013

As you can see, short, concise, bug-free.

Comment: I was waiting to get enough reputation to come back and comment on this post, but I see you removed the last few lines about me initially fixing his code. I just wanted to say that my edit was solely intended to get rid of the bug so people could focus on helping him with his actual problem. Your response should be marked as the correct solution. I agree - its clean, short, concise, and bug-free :).

Comment: @KurtKing there was no offense intended. You were new to this site and you edited the code in a question with the best intentions! This is a well-known problem around here (fixing code in a quesion *will* invalidate answers) so I only was a bit mad about the reviewers: they have more experience and they *should* reject an edit request attempting to fix the code. Now you know and I guess you'll do a good job reviewing edit requests :)

Comment: of course! I appreciate the information and that makes a lot of sense. I will make note of this for the future. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim)` splits the string from the start to the first occurrence of `delim`. Returns the cut string but modifies stringp when passed.